# Docusign - add a supplemental document

Tags: docusignapi

is it possible to attach to the below a supplemental pdf.  This pdf is created at run time and requires no signatures or user input.  I would like it attached as a supplemental document.  Is this possible using the method below which is using template hosted with docu sign. Looked this up but cant find a solution to work with the below.  Thanks

Jon

```
data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
        "emailSubject" => "Your Zurich Application",
        "templateId" => $templateId, 
        "templateRoles" => array( 
                array( "email" => $toemail, "name" => $recipientName,     "roleName" => $templateRoleName,
                "tabs" => array( "textTabs" => array ( array (
                                        "tabLabel" => "ftname",
                                        "value" => $zurich->getColumnVal("fname")),
                                        array (
                                        "tabLabel" => "lname",
                                        "value" => $zurich->getColumnVal("b_fname")),


)))),
        "status" => "sent");
```

Comment: Is the "supplemental" document ready when the envelope is created? Should the supplemental document be visible to all recipients of the envelope? Please update your question (edit your question) with the additional information. You can include multiple documents in an envelope easily, either at envelope creation time or later.

Comment: Larry, thanks so much for the reply.  yes, is the answer to both.  I have however worked out another route to achieve what we needed.  I would love to learn how to do the above however.  Is there a guide somewhere that i may have missed?

Comment: What would you like info on? Adding multiple documents when creating the envelope or adding additional documents to a draft envelope or adding documents to an envelope that is in-flight? Please ask as a new question. Good work on solving this question's issue. Please post an answer to this question giving the solution that you settled upon.